# Union-find data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, union-find

For many problems I see the solution recommended is to use a union-find data structure. I tried to read about it and think about how it is implemented (using C++). My current understanding is that it is nothing but a list of sets. So to find which set an element belongs we require `n*log n` operations. And when we have to perform union, then we have to find the two sets which needs to be merged and do a `set_union` on them. This doesn't look terribly efficient to me. Is my understanding of this data structure correct or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm, not sure what you mean by "union-find data structure."  Can you elaborate, or provide a descriptive link?

Comment: This one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: "Introduction to Algorithms" (the first cite in the linked Wikipedia article) provides a thorough discussion.

Answer (score 21):

This is quite late reply, but this has probably not been answered elsewhere on stackoverflow, and since this is top most page for someone searching for union-find, here is the detailed solution.

Find-Union is a very fast operation, performing in near constant time. 
It follows Jeremie's insights of path compression, and tracking set sizes. Path compression is performed on each find operation itself, thereby taking amortized lg*(n) time. lg* is like the inverse Ackerman function, growing so very slow that it is rarely beyond 5 (at least till n< 2^65535). Union/Merge sets is performed lazy, by just pointing 1 root to another, specifically smaller set's root to larger set's root, which is completed in constant time.

Refer the below code from https://github.com/kartikkukreja/blog-codes/blob/master/src/Union%20Find%20%28Disjoint%20Set%29%20Data%20Structure.cpp

```
class UF {
  int *id, cnt, *sz;
  public:
// Create an empty union find data structure with N isolated sets.
UF(int N) {
    cnt = N; id = new int[N]; sz = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)  id[i] = i, sz[i] = 1; }
~UF() { delete[] id; delete[] sz; }

// Return the id of component corresponding to object p.
int find(int p) {
    int root = p;
    while (root != id[root])    root = id[root];
    while (p != root) { int newp = id[p]; id[p] = root; p = newp; }
    return root;
}
// Replace sets containing x and y with their union.
void merge(int x, int y) {
    int i = find(x); int j = find(y); if (i == j) return;
    // make smaller root point to larger one
    if (sz[i] < sz[j]) { id[i] = j, sz[j] += sz[i]; }
    else { id[j] = i, sz[i] += sz[j]; }
    cnt--;
}
// Are objects x and y in the same set?
bool connected(int x, int y) { return find(x) == find(y); }
// Return the number of disjoint sets.
int count() { return cnt; }
};
```

Comment: lg*(n) [Iterated Logarithm, commonly pronounced "Log Star of n"] is not the inverse ackermann function. It goes very slowly yes, and can also be considered as a small consistent for any conceivably useful values of n, but they're still different functions and the latter is represented with an alpha. It happens to be that Union-Find functions were proved to run in alpha(n) time

Comment: It seems that the rank compression proposed in the code above does not follow the prescibed approach which should approximate and minimize the *depth* of the trees rather than their number of nodes (which will be the same in the resulting tree whatever the chosen parent node). In the merge function, when `sz[i] < sz[j]` then you should only `id[i] = j` since the depth of `j` does not change with the fusion. same when `sz[j] < sz[i]` inverting `i` and `j`. It's only when `sz[i] == sz[j]` that you can choose any as parent, and should increment the parent's `sz` by *one*.

Comment: As pointed by Nicholas, it's complexity is lg*(n) [Iterated Logarithm, commonly pronounced "Log Star of n"]. It's different from inverse-ackermann, though both move very slowly and are <10 for conceivably useful values of n.

Comment: Vincent, sz[] stores the size of each isolated set, in the root node of that set. e.g. 1-{2,3,4}, 5-{6{7}} shall merge 5 into 1. This way it's simpler, as find() as side-effect changes tree depth buy not size.

Comment: @AtifHussain you are right that find changes depth, but the complexity of the operations depend on the depths of the trees and not on their size. That is what should be minimized. The *exact* depths are indeed not easily computed, but with the modifications suggested an upper bound of the depth is computed, and that's enough to improve the complexity. That's at least the approach described in the Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al.

Answer (score 5):

The data structure can be represented as a tree, with branches reversed (instead of pointing down, the branches point upwards to the parent---and link a child with its parent).

If I remember correctly, it can be shown (easily):

- that path compression (whenever you do a lookup for the "parent" of a set A, you "compress" the path so that each future call to these will provide the parent in time O(1)) will lead to O(log n) complexity per call;
- that balancing (you keep approximately track of the number of children each set has, and when you have to "unite" two sets, you make the one with the fewer children child of the one with the most) also leads to a O(log n) complexity per call.

A more involved proof can show that when you combine both optimizations, you obtain an average complexity that is the inverse Ackermann function, written α(n), and this was Tarjan's main invention for this structure.

It was later shown, I believe, that for some specific usage patterns, this complexity is actually constant (though for all practical purpose inverse of ackermann is about 4). According to the Wikipedia page on Union-Find, in 1989, the amortized cost per operation of any equivalent data structure was shown to be Ω(α(n)), proving that the current implementation is asymptotically optimal.

Answer (score 2):

A proper union-find data structure uses path compression during every find. This amortizes the cost and each operation is then proportional to the inverse of the ackermann function which basically makes it constant (but not quite).

If you are implementing it from scratch then I would suggest using a tree-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

A simple union-set structure keeps an array (element -> set), making finding which set constant time; updating them is amortized log n time and concatenating the lists is constant. Not as quick as some of the approaches above, but trivial to program and more then good enough to improve the Big-O running time of, say, Kruskal's Minimal Spanning Tree Algorithm.