# How do you obtain the set corresponding to a number in O(1)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set, primes

Lets say there are N numbers grouped into K disjoint sets. The problem is to create a key for each of these disjoint sets such that given any number, a simple operation on these keys and the number should be able to give the set containing the number.

*A simple approach and it’s limitations:* 
                          For ex. Let the N numbers be 34,35,36….321 Let set 1 be made of 63,66,77,89,122,222 And set 2 be made of 53,69,137,230,280,299,300,306 And so on..

*sol:*
first an array of prime numbers containing (321-34=287) items is created. To create a key for the first set, the prime numbers corresponding to positions (63-34),(66-34),…(222-34) in the array are multiplied. Now this key is divisible only by prime numbers corresponding to the numbers in set 1 and not otherwise. So, given 77, [if(key1%(primeArray[77-34]==0)], 77 belongs to set1

But since I’m dealing with large number of data values, the keys cannot be represented by even 64 bit integers(and I don’t want to split the keys). Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Formatting is your friend btw...

Comment: A bitmap doesn't do this easily?

Comment: Are both N and K large? If both are small, a single hashtable mapping numbers to sets would work. If K is small, a bloom filter for each of the K sets could be a start. Are the numbers and their arrangement into sets completely arbitrary, or is there any more structure to exploit?

Comment: @Barmar yes,I am currently using a simple bitmap, but I want to conserve as much space as possible because N can range from 0-20/30k. 
I haven't tried the bloom filter approach before. Will try that out now. As mentioned, N usually varies from 0-20000/30000 and is consecutive. K is usually around 20-50

Comment: This doesn't seem possible with 64-bit numbers. If each of the N numbers can be placed in one of K sets, then there are K^N possible distributions (some sets may be empty, so the amount required by the problem would be a little less, but this argument is dealing with order of magnitude.) Let X be the size of each key. Then for the keys to cover all cases, X^K=K^N. This means X=K^(N/K). For N=30,000 and K=50, X needs to be a 3386-bit number approx to contain the necessary amount of info. I'm interested if I'm overlooking something..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a classic case to use union find data structure.
[Union-find data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300125/union-find-data-structure)

Give each number a rank. Trivially, the number itself in this case. The highest rank in a set represents the set.